# Indy Components Unusable

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, indy

I have placed a TIdFTP component on my form and when I go into my code, I see this:

[image]

I have a feeling that the library paths may be incorrect.

[image]

Does anyone know what this problem could be?
Thank you in advanced for your answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you thought, your search paths do not include the Indy folder. You have it in the Debug DCUs path, but not in the Library path.

Comment: So are you saying that I should copy the Debug DCU Path into the Library Path?

Comment: I have gotten my program to compile now. I have changed the Library Path to: $(BDS)\lib;$(BDS)\Lib\Indy10;

Comment: That is obviously true, but code insight can often give you erroneous squiggly lines at times!

Comment: Misha is right. Check if it builds, and the squiggly lines before it builds do not always indicate that your app won't build.

Answer (score 4):

Yes - code insight gets confused at times. Ignore the red squiggly lines. For me the Delphi IDE has been suffering from these symptoms at times for over 10 years, and I have just learnt to live with it. If you want, closing and restarting Delphi sometimes gets code insight back in "sync".

Comment: +1. This is actually `Error Insight`, which is part of `Code Insight`. I find the best thing to do is just disable it (`Tools->Options->Editor Options->Code Insight`, uncheck `Error Insight`) because it doesn't work correctly. I check again with every new version of the IDE, and when it's still buggy I turn it off for that version too. :)

Comment: The "IDE Fix Pack" fixes these bugs, at least in D2010. No need to turn it off; it's quite useful when it works.

Comment: @awmross, yes, it works most of the time, and when it does it is very useful. When it doesn't it is pretty obvious so having it on is more benefit than turning it off!